# Performance problems with Credant desktop encryption, is uninstall an option?

Tags: windows, performance, encryption

I'm having a performance problem with [Credant](http://www.credant.com) when accessing a lot of files, such as during a code compile. What happens is that on my dual-core box the combined CPU hits 50% and the "system" part (the red part of the performance graph in `taskman.exe`) is the bulk of that. According to SysInternals' Process Explorer the driver `CMGSCHEF.SYS` is taking all the CPU.

As far as I can tell, only the mobile policy rules are installed, my whole hard drive isn't encrypted.

(For those lucky enough to not have to use Credant, it's a half-baked whole-disk encryption and policy management package that has a lot of issues, performance impact being one.)

Any ideas for this? Thanks! -ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Credant software can be uninstalled by administrators, but not generally by end users short of the previous wipe/reinstall suggestion.  Note well that the software has an audit system that allows administrators to be aware if the software does not check in within their configured monitoring period.  So if you did uninstall, you can expect them to be aware that you've done so.

If performance is a concern, you could reach out to your administrator to ask whether they can tune your policy for a development environment rather than the typical business user's arrangement if they haven't already done so.  If you need to track down the administrator to contact, you could email the support group at [Credant](http://www.credant.com/company-info/contact-us.html) and ask them to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Ok.. the good and the bad... you CAN uninstall Credant.  Once you look at the "CredantInstall.Log file on the C: drive you will see a in the log a hex key, like {00db2a6e-.....}.  By typing in the command line msiexec.exe -x{.....} it will uninstall Credant.. Problem is, the files are encrypted on a system level, and without the admin utility. Goodbye files.  Fix?? Sorry, Credant is very invasive.  Best bet is to catch it first.  This has beema nightmare for my facility.  With a 3.7% failure rate, or 117 machines, it takes over an hour to backup the files, reimage and put back in to production.  Seems these issues is their learning curve. Step up Credant!

Comment: Step up...to another full disk encryption method, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Credant Shield disables the windows XP (and probably Vista) prefetch capabilities, at least at the 6.6 version level.

I'd recommend uninstalling it until credant repairs this very fundamental issue with system performance

Answer (score 1):

It says "Uninstallable" on the web site. This is usually a feature of this type of software. You could always email their support if you haven't already. Otherwise, a complete disk wipe and reinstall would probably be required.

If this isn't an install you bought from them, you're on your own.

Answer (score 1):

If I had the ability to comment, I would've just commented on Richard Phillips answer.

Unfortunately, we are also using Credant software and are required to have it installed. Our administrators were able to make an exception for us (company developers), so that a specified folder ("C:\Dev" in our case) would be excluded from the encryption process.

Performance is noticeably better, and various issues with Visual Studio and Subversion have gone away.

Comment: Developers in another group in my company had to get a similar special dispensation from the security group for the same thing, as they were having abysmal performance on Java builds having 50k files.